# Updating iOS/iPhone app with new localization/ replacing resources

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, installation

I have an iPhone application that is already on the app-store and is not localized. In the new version of the app, I want to add more localizations to it, the localization includes text translation and images/xibs localization.

I have tried to update the app on top of the current store build, the texts are appearing localized, but it is keeping the old/un-localized images/xibs and not using the new/localized ones.

Anybody has faced such an issue? Is there any way to force fresh re-installation of iOS app ?

Please advice, appreciate your kind help.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue.  I have cleaned the build and ensured the original unlocalized images are not included in the new build.  It appears the original unlocalized images are being kept on existing app installations and are being displayed instead of the localized versions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clean the project and rebuild when changing bundled resources.

Answer (score 0):

Also do a reinstall of your app. Remove it on your device/simulator, clean in Xcode and run again.